# python delete dict keys in list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Why is the following expression, aiming at deleting multiple keys in a dict, invalid? (`event` is a dict)

```
[del event[key] for key in ['selected','actual','previous','forecast']]
```

What would be the most minimal expression to replace it with?

Comment: No, it is not valid, because `del` is not an expression. Don't use list comprehensions for side effects, **only** for building a list of values.

Comment: `for key in ['selected','actual','previous','forecast']: del event[key]`

Comment: Python won't even accept such a line as valid code.  There can't be statements in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should not use a list comprehension **at all** here. List comprehensions are great at building a list of values, and should not be used for general looping. Using a list comprehension for the side-effects is a waste of memory on a perfectly good list object.

List comprehensions are also *expressions*, so can only contain other expressions. `del` is a statement and can't be used inside an expression.

Just use a `for` loop:

```
# use a tuple if you need a literal sequence; stored as a constant
# with the code object for fast loading
for key in ('selected', 'actual', 'previous', 'forecast'):
    del event[key]
```

or rebuild the dictionary with a dictionary comprehension:

```
# Use a set for fast membership testing, also stored as a constant
event = {k: v for k, v in event.items()
         if k not in {'selected', 'actual', 'previous', 'forecast'}}
```

The latter creates an entirely new dictionary, so other existing references to the same object won't see any changes.

If you must use key deletion in an expression, you can use `object.__delitem__(key)`, but this is not the place; you'd end up with a list with `None` objects as a result, a list you discard immediately.