# How to delete column before clicking on import using Django import export in admin

Tags: django, django-import-export

I want to delete some columns from a csv before I import it to the model In admin. It has some overridable functions in https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.after_import_row
but I do not know how to edit it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the [tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#removing-rows-columns) object in memory before you call the django-import-export `import_data()` function.

For example, to remove a column, it is very simple:

```py
del data['Col Name']
```

Comment: im sorry this might sound stupid but if i want to say delete multiple coloumns such as name email and password, would i be able to do it and how? like I typed in "del data['name', 'password'] " but i got 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: You can either call del in a [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43632891/39296) or use [slicing](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#removing-rows-columns)

Comment: since the csv is not uploaded yet im getting IndexError: list assignment index out of range as there is no index value to be deleted. And when i use 
for key in ('name', 'password'):
     del data[key]
i get TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
I believe i am calling the function itself but im really confused as to how to go on about this.

Comment: I would suggest edit your question to try to give us more detail about what you are trying to do. Please include code snippets.  Are you importing via the admin console?

Comment: I edited it. And yes im trying to import from admin. I just need to edit the same file over and over and to save it in the model for logs and export the formated file with the data from the models.

Comment: Its done. My logic was completley wrong. I just used the exclude = option and just ignored the coloumns.