# Deleting an item in a dictionary using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I delet an item from a dictionary if the value of an item is a specific string, using dictionay comprehension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python delete dict keys in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632814/python-delete-dict-keys-in-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the other ones

```
values = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '4', 'd': '4'}
toRemove = '4'
values = {k: v for k, v in values.items() if v != toRemove}
print(values)  # {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```